# .net IEnumerable Except with custom IEqualityComparer not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am currently a bit confused with the IEnumerable.Except() Method. I tried to perform set operations build on the data id of Objects. So, I wrote a custom Equality Comparer. But the result is totally not what I expected.
The example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> IntList1 = new List<int> { 42, 43 };
        List<int> IntList2 = new List<int> { 42 };

        var intResultList = IntList1.Except(IntList2).ToList();
        intResultList.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

        List<DataStructure> List1 = new List<DataStructure> { new DataStructure { DataID = 42, SomeText = "42" }, new DataStructure {DataID = 43, SomeText = "43"} };
        List<DataStructure> List2 = new List<DataStructure> { new DataStructure { DataID = 42, SomeText = "42" }};

        var comparer = new DataStructureComparer();

        var resultList = List1.Except(List2, comparer).ToList();

        resultList.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s.SomeText));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class DataStructureComparer: IEqualityComparer<DataStructure>
{

    public bool Equals(DataStructure x, DataStructure y)
    {
        return x.DataID == y.DataID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataStructure obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class DataStructure
{
    public int DataID;
    public string SomeText;
}
```

The Output goes like this:
43
42
43

But I would have expected it to be 
43
43

Why is my assumption wrong?

brgds
Sven Weiberg

Comment: what happens if you change `GetHashCode()` to return a constant like `0`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for this is your implementation of `GetHashCode()`. It gives different hashcodes for all your `DataStructure` instances.

Change it to something like:

```
public int GetHashCode(DataStructure obj)
{
    return obj.DataID;
}
```

---

To increase performance, `Except` will at first compare the hash codes of the objects. Only if they are equal it will call `Equals` to determine if the objects are really *equal* in your meaning of equal.

Different hashes tell it that the objects are not equal. And you use the base implementation of `object.GetHashCode()` which will mostly give different values for different *instances*.

Since your equality is determined by the `DataID` property, it makes sense to use this value as hash code, too.

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem.